# Discord Python Bot: List of players in json

Tags: python, json, discord, command

What i'm trying to achive is to make three simple commands:

!add nick

!delete nick

!list (of nicknames)

This is my not-so-well-working script:

```
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')



def add(name):
    list.append( name )

@bot.command()
async def dele(ctx, *args):
    with open('list.json', 'r') as f:
        lines = json.loads(f.read())

    for name in args:
        lines.remove(name)

    with open('list.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(lines))

@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, *args):
    with open('list.json', 'r') as f:
        lines = json.loads(f.read())

    for name in args:
        lines.append(name)

    with open('list.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(lines))


@bot.command()
async def list(ctx):
    with open('list.json', 'r') as f:
     
        list = json.loads(f.read())
        await ctx.channel.send(f"List {list}")

bot.run("MY TOKEN HERE")
```

Command !list output:

[image: command !list output]

list.json
`["test1", "test2", "test3", "test", "4", "test4", "name", "name", "test", "5", "test", "6"]`

So... adding and deleting nicknames works fine (except that when i'm trying to add nickname with spaces its adding two separate keys).

But the biggest problem i got with the list command. Don't know how to format this to some kind of list with \n nicknames showing one by one or even with discord embed thing.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Spaces

---

> (except that when i'm trying to add nickname with spaces its adding two separate keys)

Remember that when you write two words separated by space, the `commands.command` takes them as two arguments. You must write them without spaces.

## One parameter function

---

You can solve your problem editing your functions like this:

```
@Bot.command()
async def add(ctx, member: str):
    with open('list.json', 'r') as f:
    lines = json.loads(f.read())

    lines.append(member)

    with open('list.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(lines))
```

## Embed

---

You can do something like this:

```
description = ""
for i in list:
    description += f'{i}\n'
```

Or

```
description = '\n'.join (list)
```

Then,

```
    emb = discord.Embed(title="List", description=description, color=discord.Color.random())
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: But you can still pass infinite arguments if the async function under `commands.command` decorator if it has `*` as a function parameter, and also pls use f-strings

Comment: @GhostOps, I know it, but his problem is with nicknames written with spaces, not with the number of arguments at all.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mI71HCK.png
Kinda working but instead of getting just one list (the last one looks good) i'm getting three of them for each of the key. How to repair this?

Comment: And about the spaces i should use ```key.replace(" ","_")``` so it would save nickname with underscore and then in list command i should change underscores to spaces with ```key.replace("_"," ")``` I guess... i just don't know how to do it in the code.

Comment: @Martin what do u mean saving nickname with underscores? are u going to pass a user's username as a parameter to a command?

Comment: I just want to use nicknames with spaces in the !add command. Like !add Martin Scorsese. To do this i need to add that name to the json file with underscore like Martin_Scorsese and then read it with !list command without underscores. To get this work i think i should use `str.replace(' ', '_')`

Comment: @Martin why are you saving them in a json with underscores as they're already a string? can i know pls?

Comment: Because now when ill use !add Martin Scorsese i'm getting two new keys "Martin" and "Scorsese" in the json file.

Comment: How can the command undertsand that Martin and Scorsese aren't two different people? There's no way to do it...

Comment: @Martin So your expected code in your mind has only one function parameter in `!add` and `!delete` commands and no parameters in `!list` command, right? i mean, the add and delete accepts only one username each time, right?

Comment: In that case I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO  well, we need to confirm that from Martin tho

Comment: I hope this will solve his problem, since otherwise I can't understand what his problem is

Comment: Sorry my english is very poor i guess. I don't want members of the discord to put on that list. I just wanted to gather there players which not always has our discord. Still i think that command !add Some Guy should be working as i previously stated. One function in !add command should change spaces to underscores and then save that name called Some_Guy in the json file as one key.
If it's not possible then lets just forget it.
@FLAK-ZOSO if you could also check your code with list again and update with this problem: https://i.imgur.com/mI71HCK.png i could mark it as solved.

Comment: Ok nvm about the list. Its working. So if no chance to make a command `!add Some Guy` i'll just mark it as solved?

Comment: I think the problem is almost solved, so you can accept the answer (or making one by you if you think there's something missing, or maybe editing mine, if you want).

Comment: Okey ill just accept this one and make another one and try to explain it a lil bit more.